# EditText background change color automatically when select an email

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-edittext

When I start my app, the email field is ok, but when I touch it, and a dropdown with some emails appear, when I select one of them, the background color of the email field suddenly change. I can't figure out why it's happening

The editText field [before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/09gAt.jpg), with the dropdown, and [after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGjeF.jpg) the problem appears

Here's the xml of the editText

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextEmail"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/emailHint"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    style="@style/loginField"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout4" />
```

And the `@style/loginField`

```
<style name="loginField">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/gray400</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/gray400</item>
    <item name="backgroundTint">@color/gray400</item>
    <item name="android:paddingTop">25dp</item>
</style>
```

Maybe I used something wrong or I'm missing something. Hope someone can help

Answer (score 1):

That color change indicates that the field was autofill-ed.

You can override this color if you want to.

```xml
<style name="AppTheme" parent="...">
    <item name="android:autofilledHighlight">#cccccc</item>
</style>
```

and then change your application to use this new theme